What is the detection mechanism for S3 "path access style fallback"?
I am trying to use Barman to back up a CNPG database cluster on S3.
The S3 service we need to use (on-premise, Huawei) requires "virtual host" access style, and Barman simply does not use it. Since Barman is using Boto3, and apparently the default access style of boto3 is "virtual host":

(Default) Attempts to use virtual, but falls back to path if necessary.

I am interested in the following:

What exactly is the process performed by boto3 to "attempt" to use virtual host access style, and what is "fallback condition"?
Where is the code for that process in the boto3 or botocore libraries?

It seems that there is (in contrast to other AWS behavior) no environment variable to force-control this, at least I could not find any in the boto3 docs.
I really don't understand why barman/boto3 apparently falls back to path-style, other services developed by us are using virtual-host-style quite happily.
Update – environment variable for access style (tl;dr - does not exist):
Looking at botocore's configprovider.py, it seems that there is no ENV variable available to specify the S3 access style explicitly:
DEFAULT_S3_CONFIG_VARS = {
    # [...]
    'addressing_style': (
        (
            's3',
            'addressing_style'
        ),                     # config file setting: s3.addressing_style
        None,                  # **HERE would be the ENV var name**
        None,                  # a default value
        None                   # a conversion function
    ),
    # [...]
}

(Interpretation of the addressing_style tuple taken from here). That was already suggested once (GitHub #3190), but declined.

hey @jonrsharpe, not sure if I ever had one of my questions edited – is that a thing now? (didnt even know that could be done ...). also not sure if it's really better now, yet I have to admit it's definitively less "nervous" ;) . thanks!

New PR for boto3: https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/3307 – 2nd attempt, let's see if this convinces them :)
